# How to select a sub XML that matches a value in PLSQL?

Tags: xml, parsing, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have some XML like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<response>   
  <HEADER>some content</HEADER>  
  <employee><name>A</name><age>32</age><type>Permanent</type></employee>
  <employee><name>B</name><age>34</age><type>Temporary</type></employee>
  <employee><name>C</name><age>63</age><type>Temporary</type></employee>
  <employee><name>D</name><age>64</age><type>Permanent</type></employee>
  <employee><name>E</name><age>54</age><type>Permanent</type></employee>
  <company><cname>Company A</cname></company>   
  <company><cname>Company B</cname></company>   
  <company><cname>Company C</cname></company>
</response>
```

and I want only the "Permanent" employee details and the header as the output. Something like,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<response>
  <HEADER>some content</HEADER>
  <employee><name>A</name><age>32</age><type>Permanent</type></employee>
  <employee><name>D</name><age>64</age><type>Permanent</type></employee>
  <employee><name>E</name><age>54</age><type>Permanent</type></employee>
</response>
```

Is there a way to get this type of output using PL/SQL ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you gonna do with that o/p in PL/SQL? I mean store it in DB or what? I don't think that is not what PL/SQL is meant for. Such kind of processing is usually done in languages like Java..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare 
v_xml xmltype := xmltype('<response>   
  <HEADER>some content</HEADER>  
  <employee><name>A</name><age>32</age><type>Permanent</type></employee>
  <employee><name>B</name><age>34</age><type>Temporary</type></employee>
  <employee><name>C</name><age>63</age><type>Temporary</type></employee>
  <employee><name>D</name><age>64</age><type>Permanent</type></employee>
  <employee><name>E</name><age>54</age><type>Permanent</type></employee>
  <company><cname>Company A</cname></company>   
  <company><cname>Company B</cname></company>   
  <company><cname>Company C</cname></company>
</response>');

begin 
dbms_output.put_line('1) Extract only Permanent employee.');
dbms_output.put_line(v_xml.extract('//response/employee[type !="Permanent"]').getClobVal());
dbms_output.put_line('  ');
dbms_output.put_line('2) Remove unnecessary node.');
dbms_output.put_line( v_xml.deleteXML('//response/employee[type !="Permanent"]').deleteXML('//response/company').getStringVal());
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract only permanent employees you can use this simple select:

```
SELECT
  xml_tab.*
FROM
  XMLTABLE(
    '/response/employee' PASSING XMLTYPE(q'#<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
        <response>   
          <HEADER>some content</HEADER>  
          <employee><name>A</name><age>32</age><type>Permanent</type></employee>
          <employee><name>B</name><age>34</age><type>Temporary</type></employee>
          <employee><name>C</name><age>63</age><type>Temporary</type></employee>
          <employee><name>D</name><age>64</age><type>Permanent</type></employee>
          <employee><name>E</name><age>54</age><type>Permanent</type></employee>
          <company><cname>Company A</cname></company>   
          <company><cname>Company B</cname></company>   
          <company><cname>Company C</cname></company>
        </response>#')
    COLUMNS 
    i FOR ORDINALITY
    ,name VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'name'
    ,age VARCHAR2(3) PATH 'age'
    ,type VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'type'
  ) xml_tab
WHERE
  xml_tab.type = 'Permanent';
```

This produces the following output:

```
I |NAME|AGE | TYPE
---------------------
1 | A  | 32 | Permanent
4 | D  | 64 | Permanent
5 | E  | 54 | Permanent
```